# "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied" when using batch jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-batch, aws-permissions

- I have a compute environment with 'ecsInstanceRole'. It contains the policies 'AmazonS3FullAccess' and 'AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role'
- Since I am using the AmazonS3FullAccess policy, I assume the batch job has permission to list, copy, put etc.
  -The image I am using is a custom docker image that has a startup script which uses "aws s3 ls <S3_bucket_URL>"
- When I start this image on an EC2 instance, it runs fine and lists the contents of the bucket
- when I do the same as a batch job, I get the access denied error seen above.

I dont understand how this is happening.

Things I have tried so far:

- having the bucket policy as

.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1546414123454",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1546414471931",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account Id>:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::"bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- Granted public access to the bucket

Comment: If you are using IAM Roles, there is **no need for a Bucket Policy**. (Also, there is a small typo in that policy, before `bucketname` but I presume that was due to a Copy & Paste error.) It would appear that a role has not been assigned to your ECS task: [IAM Roles for Tasks - Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for that answer! It is finally working. I attached a S3 access policy to my current Job Role and now It executes just fine. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the reply from @JohnRotenstein because I cannot mark it as an answer.

"If you are using IAM Roles, there is no need for a Bucket Policy. (Also, there is a small typo in that policy, before bucketname but I presume that was due to a Copy & Paste error.) It would appear that a role has not been assigned to your ECS task: [IAM Roles for Tasks - Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)"

**Solution**: I had toattach an S3 access policy to my current Job Role.